# How would I access the third column in a many to many table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a table to record likes for users in mysql and I have added a boolean column to check if this user has liked a specific post, but I'm not too sure how to access my third boolean column. I am using flask-sqlalchemy. I'm open to better ways to do this as well.

```
likes = db.Table('likes',
    db.Column('Users_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('Post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('Liked_status', db.Boolean, default = False)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need boolean column Here. This is sufficient for your case:

```
likes = db.Table('likes',
    db.Column('Users_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('Post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'), primary_key=True),
)
```

if record for given user.id and post.id exist, it means that post.id is liked by user.id. So `like` method should create the record, while `unlike` should delete the record.

To check if `user_id` liked `post_id` you can execute query:

```py
exist_like = session.query(likes).filter(likes.c.user_id == user_id, likes.c.post_id == post_id).one()
```